# MySQLException Access Denied When Using Allow User Variables = TRUE

Tags: c#, mysql

The DB Code that I've written requires that I use Allow User Variables in my connection string.  Without this setting, I am to login to the DB; with this setting, I am unable to login.

Here is an example of the code:

**new MySqlConnection:**

```
("server=XX.XX.XX.XX;
Port=3306;
database=store;
UserID=XXX;
password=XXX;
Allow User Variables=TRUE");
```

I have changed the access privileges for the user, but this has no effect on my ability to connect to the DB.  Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing incorrectly?  One other note, the DB is hosted on a different server than where this code is running.

Comment: nothing is blocking that port.  I am able to make the connection without the AllowUserVariables in the connection string.

Comment: 'unable to login' <- can you be more specific? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: MySQLException:  Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xxx' (using password: YES)

Comment: you mean like this:  server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Port=3306;database=store;UserID=XXX;password=XXXX;AllowUserVariables=TRUE;old syntax=yes;  if so, this did not make a difference.

Comment: Take out the spaces between "Allow User Variables"

Comment: 5.5.15 for mysql version.  not sure about mysql .net connector.  how do i find out which one?

Comment: Solution explorer -> References, look for the MySQL entry and check the properties.
Tried everything I can think of, but cannot reproduce this behaviour (server 5.5.41, current connector version through nuget).

Comment: to which solution explorer are you referring?

Comment: the connector is 6.9.6.0